# SQL Query fails every time... PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I want to insert price, sku and link from variuse CSV files to a database. To do that I iterate through each CSV file and stack up a string with the values (`$sql`). But it won't get inserted into my database...

This is a example of how I stack up the `$sql` string:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO cron (sku, price, link) VALUES" . " \n";


    if((stripos($inputFilename, "bok24"))){
        // Loop through each row creating a <row> node with the correct data
        while (($row = fgetcsv($inputFile, 0, $delimiter)) !== false) {
            if(($row[0] != null) || ($row[0] != "")){
                $sql .= "(\"" . $row[0] . "\",\"" . $row[4] . "\",\"" . $row[20] . "\"),";
            }
        } 

    ... other CSV files
```

To check where the error is I print the `$sql` string into a file. I print the string to a file before he get`s escaped by`mysqli_real_escape(...)` and afterwords...

```
    $myfile = fopen("data/sql.txt", "a");
    fwrite($myfile, $sql . "\n\n");
    fclose($myfile);

    $sql = substr($sql, 0, -1) . ";";
    $sql = $GLOBALS["database"]->real_escape_string($sql);

    if($GLOBALS["database"]->query($sql) === TRUE){
        echo "Successfully transfered to database!\n";
    }else{
        echo "ERROR by transferring to database!\n";
    }

    $myfile = fopen("data/sql.txt", "a");
    fwrite($myfile, $sql . "\n\n");
    fclose($myfile);
```

In this file you can find the escaped and not escaped variation. But I do not see my error... Can somebody please help me and tell me where my error is?

[Here you can find the sql.txt file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzLxINxZFzovdldDX2hDYVRGU3c/view?usp=sharing) (search for \n to get to the next sql string in the file).

Greetings and Thank You!

Comment: Ideally MySQL do not have an single insert statement value limit. 
However, you are probably hitting the limit of **max_allowed_packet** which is 1MB by default. You can try to change max_allowed_packet size limit of MySql or you can split your insert statement to multiple insert statements.

Comment: break it up into multiple inserts of 100 rows each, it's too big an insert for your settings in one SQL statement.

Comment: Why you need single insert query ? you can insert that data within loop ?

Comment: what kind of error do you have? your db bar is not very properly set up and shown. extract it locally `$db = $GLOBALS["database"]` and then check if connection was initialized. Could you execute any simple qeury? like `if($GLOBALS["database"]->query('SELECT "my db is ok";') === TRUE){` ?

Comment: I want to do it with one sql query per csv because each csv contains around 5000 rows and I have 12 of them. So I would end up by 60.000 sql queries... - But the SQL statement is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like:

```
    if((stripos($inputFilename, "bok24"))){
        // Loop through each row creating a <row> node with the correct data
       $counter_inserted = 0;
        while (($row = fgetcsv($inputFile, 0, $delimiter)) !== false) {
            if(($row[0] != null) || ($row[0] != "")){
                $sql = "INSERT INTO cron (sku, price, link) VALUES" . " \n";
                $sql .= "(\"" . $GLOBALS["database"]->real_escape_string($row[0]) . "\",\"" . $GLOBALS["database"]->real_escape_string($row[4]) . "\",\"" . $GLOBALS["database"]->real_escape_string($row[20]) . "\"),";
                if($GLOBALS["database"]->query($sql)){
                     $counter_inserted++;
                }
            }
        }
```

`echo $counter_inserted;` will show you how much record were inserted